# Gradle application plugin | Incorrect 'lib' folder in generated script

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to use Gradle application plugins as follows:-

**build.gradle** :-

```
group 'com.samsoft'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

defaultTasks("clean", "build")

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'idea'
mainClassName = 'com.samsoft.Main'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

**src/main/java.Main.java** :-

```
package com.samsoft;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

After running gradle build, we have PRJECT/build/libs & PROJECT/build/scripts folders create and others. The libs has executable jar and its dependencies and scripts has .bat and .sh files to run the application.

**PROBLEM**

The script file has incorrect classpath as `set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\hello-gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

's' character is missing from lib which results in `Error: Could not find or load main class com.samsoft.Main` while trying to run it.

How can I fix this ?

Gradle 3.5
Java 8

Answer (score 3):

Scripts in the `scripts` dir are not meant to be run, there are here just to be included in the final distribution.

If you take a look in the `distributions` dir, you can see a tar and and zip archive. These will contain both scripts at the root and a `lib` dir which containing jar files. This is what the `CLASSPATH` is about :

```
CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\hello-gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

`%APP_HOME%` is the folder where the files have been unzipped / untarred